# p:ajax only executed in first element of p:dataGrid

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a `p:dataGrid` with some images and want the user to select one of them

```
<h:form id="f1">
 <p:dataGrid var="image" value="#{bean.images}"
             columns="3" rows="1" paginator="true"
             paginatorTemplate="{PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink}">

  <h:graphicImage value="#{image.url}" width="200">
    <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.selectImage(image.url)}"/>
  </h:graphicImage>

 </p:dataGrid>  
</h:form>
```

Unfortunately I get the method `public void selectImage(String url)` only invoked for the first element in the `p:dataGrid` (and it's possible to click this image multiple times). Im using PrimeFaces-4.0 and JBoss-7.2

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid `<h:graphicImage>` does not support ajax, you are probably better off wrapping it in a `<p:commandLink>`. But even though the only way I could force UICommand to invoke the right method was by using `<f:setPropertyActionListener>`

```
<p:dataGrid var="image" value="#{bean.images}"
         columns="3" rows="1" paginator="true"
         paginatorTemplate="{PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink}">

    <p:commandLink action="#{bean.selectImage()}" process="@this" update="@none">
      <h:graphicImage value="#{image.url}" width="200"/>
      <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.selectedImage}" value="#{image.url}" />
    </p:commandLink>

</p:dataGrid>
```

**BackingBean**

```
public void selectImage()
{
    select(selectedImage);
    selectedImage = null;
}

private String selectedImage;
//Getter/Setter
```

BTW. you might want to read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183) especially #4

Comment: I cannot verify that h:graphicImage does not provide ajax. I tried your proposal using `<p:commandLink>`, but the problem is still the same: The method is only invoked if I click on the _first_ image!

Comment: have you tried setting selected image via `f:setPropertyActionListener` ?

Comment: I believe Primefaces stated somewhere that their `<p:ajax>` supported all components, but I would only rely on that to certain extent.